# How to run adb exec-out command using com.android.ddmlib.IDevice?

Tags: android, kotlin, adb, ddmlib

I need to execute an `adb exec-out` command using the `com.android.ddmlib.IDevice` but I was only able to run `adb shell` commands. Is it possible to execute that using this class? Otherwise I would need to run the `adb` as a Proccess but I'm trying to avoid that.

Here is how I usually run `adb shell` commands

```
fun runCommand(device: IDevice, command: String): String {
    val outputReceiver = CollectingOutputReceiver()
    // How to run adb/adb exec-out commands instead (not shell)?
    device.executeShellCommand(command, outputReceiver)
    return outputReceiver.output
}
```

Thanks!